# Need help about jquery each animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery. I want to develop a tooltip animation that will appear on 1st house (far left), then appear on 2nd house, then same on 3rd and fourth and again starts from the first. I also want to hover effect on house too. When mouse will over on any house than corresponding tooltip of that house will appear. Here is the code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bubble = $('.bubble-tooltip');
    bubble
        .eq(0).delay(1500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow')
        .eq(1).delay(2000).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow')
        .eq(2).delay(2500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow')
        .eq(4).delay(3000).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');

    $('.cloud').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).animate(
            {'left': -35},
            {duration: 2000}
        )
        //bubble.delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
        $('.bg-overlay').fadeIn(2000)
    });

});
```

I've tried other methods too to achieve my goal but no luck. Need help and thanks in advance.
And here is the site url. http://umairdesigner.com/builder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this:

```
var bubble = $('.bubble-tooltip');
var j = 0;
$(bubble).each(function(i){
    $(bubble[j]).delay(1500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(bubble[j + 1]).delay(1500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
        j++;
    });
});
```

or in case of 4 fixed houses:

```
var bubble = $('.bubble-tooltip');
  bubble.eq(0).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    bubble.eq(1).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
      bubble.eq(2).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        bubble.eq(3).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
          bubble.eq(4).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: oh thanks. let me apply it then let you know. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your budbbles showing:

```
var bubble = $('.bubble-tooltip');

bubble.eq(0).delay(1500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
bubble.eq(1).delay(2000).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
bubble.eq(2).delay(2500).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
bubble.eq(4).delay(3000).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

It won't work chained together because the return value of `.fadeOut('slow')` won't be your bubble collection - so further use of `.eq()` won't work.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But this isn't what exactly i want. I want to tooltip appear on 1st house then stay about 3-5 seconds then fadeout. Then Appear on Second House and stay about 3-5s and so on to last one. then comes to first house. this will be some kind of loop that will continues with same delay timing. thanks again

Comment: The hover is trivial - you can work that out from JQuery docs.

Comment: ok I'll take care of hover function but plz help me about the tooltip animation. that will continually repeating on all houses sequence wise.